# Unity Scene loading times are extremly long

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to Unity so not much excperience with the IDE.
I'm developing a pretty basic application, a Login and a dashboard with some basic UI elements.

The problem i encounter is when i try to switch scenes. So from the LoginScene to the Dashboard scene it can take up to 20 seconds.
There isn't even much logic that the script has to run.
This is way to long in my opinion, someone knows how to optimise my code or at least knows what i'm doing wrong ?

This is the code for checking correct user and changing scene.

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //get values from inputfields
    emailString = email.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
    passwordString = password.GetComponent<InputField>().text;

    btnLogin = login.GetComponent<Button>();
    btnLogin.onClick.AddListener(ValidateLogin);
}

private void ValidateLogin()
{
    if (emailString.Trim() == "aa" && passwordString.Trim() == "aa")
    {
        print("login succeeded!");

        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
    else
    {
        print("wrong credentials");
    }

}
```

Btw: The number 1 is the reference to my next scene, the Dashboard scene.

Comment: Just a question: why are you adding the listener in Update, and not in the Start? I suspect that's the problem.

Comment: Well there are several problems. You should migrate almost everything everything from `Update` to `Start`. There is no need to get component or add listener several times. Also assign value to `emailString` in `ValidateLogin`.

Comment: @Andrea thank you very much! don't know why i wrote it in update. Was a very stupid mistake.

Comment: @AliKanat code runs much smoother now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetComponent<>()` is a resoruce intensive task, and you are calling 3 of it unnecesarily, you also add an event listener every frame too.

What you should do is:
Read what Update, Awake, Start does, then remove the `GetComponent<>()` part and use a property or field instead, and dont add the eventlistener every frame too.

```
InputField emailInputField;
InputField passwordInputField;
Button loginButton;

// Setting up the Scene
void Awake()
{
    emailInputField = email.GetComponent<Inputfield>();
    passwordInputField = password.GetComponent<InputField>();
    loginButton = login.GetComponent<Button>();

    loginButton.onClick.AddListener(ValidateLogin);
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //get values from inputfields
    emailString = emailInputField.text;
    passwordString = passwordInputField.text;
}

private void ValidateLogin()
{
    if (emailString.Trim() == "aa" && passwordString.Trim() == "aa")
    {
        print("login succeeded!");

        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
    else
    {
        print("wrong credentials");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot! I'm starting to see how this Unity event systems works.

Comment: Glad it helped you, this is still not the smartest way to do this tho, but for your learning curve this fits

Comment: You care to share with me the "smartest" way to do it ? Really want to know the "best" way from the start, so my learning process will go a lot smoother.

Comment: Well sure, it affects your performance no more in measurable way, but why checking the string every frame?, it is enough to validate it when you click on the login button, so i would read it in the `ValidateLogin()` function(this is how online login forms work they only validate on button push), so basically your Update function is unnecesary here, also another note Unity will add update function by default, but if you do not use any logic in the `Update()` function you should delete it because in a bigger project it would affect your performance in a measurable way

Comment: And the reason for this is that the engine will call that empty `Update()` function

Answer (score 0):

Converting my comment: the Listener was added in the `Update()`, not in the `Start()`. So, it was assigned every frame.

Comment: Do you know what i makes the code slow though ? 
wouldn't there be endless listeners, so there would be an infinte loop and my code would just freeze?
how does the button know what listener it should take ?